# Can banger (in context of a song) be used as a noun?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, slang

I wrote this sentence and something seems off about it:

> Some of their stuff are complete bangers.

Can't place my finger on what's wrong. Is *banger* not supposed to be used as a noun? or is it not supposed to be used in the plural form at all?

Comment: "Some" and "are" seem a little off. Surely you should have "Some of their stuff is..."

Comment: Some of their stuff is complete banger? That also doesn't make sense
Some of their stuff is complete bangers? Even less sense

Comment: No. That is even more incorrect. What I said was that the first half of your sentence was already wrong.

Comment: “Some of their songs are complete bangers” (fixing the plural issue) sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: Certainly it's a noun if the song is about bangers and mash.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense because you're trying to pair the singular 'stuff' with the plural 'are'.  'Stuff' is uncountable so you can't say 'stuffs'.  You're going to have to change that noun to a countable one.

Janus has it right with “Some of their songs are complete bangers”.

General reference available on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-stuff-singular-or-plural) and [over here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/is-stuff-a-plural-word/1235)